# Why is my reputation not shown in the "other communities" section?

Tags: bug

Consider:

[image]

See that the reputation is not shown for the physics community.
Why is this happening? And is there a solution?

Comment: A [freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) on the screenshot would improve it.

Comment: I don’t reproduce this problem for my account on Safari (iOS) or Firefox (Android). Can you specify which browsers (including version information) and what platforms you see this behavior on?

Comment: @rob, in all browsers, chrome(Android), Firefox (windows latest), crome(windows)

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and tagged this for review by SE, who might have tools to say whether this is something particular about your account. Please let us know here if the issue resolves itself spontaneously.

Comment: My Firefox v88.0.1 (64 bit, up to date at the time of posting) on Windows 7 (yep) does show my reputation in that menu both in Physics SE and the Physics Meta SE if that info is useful to anyone.

Comment: Your Physics.SE account is shown on [the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/21018270/pranjal?tab=accounts) but not on per-site's profile ("hidden community" is irrelevant since it's not used here). There's certainly an issue with your account, possibly due to deleted/merged account shenanigans (if you did it before). This needs SE staff to fix.

Comment: @prAnjal Does this issue persist on your account?